# Service failing to wait for internet connection

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, services

I'm strying to make my systemd service start after internet connection has been established. I read [several](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78991/running-a-script-after-an-internet-connection-is-established) [questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78991/running-a-script-after-an-internet-connection-is-established) on this forum, but no success so far. The error is analog to `Invalid host: somedomain.net`

However, running `sudo systemctl restart myservice.service` *does* make the service run succesfully. I'm using Raspbian om my RPI 3 B+.

The myservice.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=my_service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/service_bash_script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

**edit1**

The script is simple and requires connection to it create a UDP stream. It's something like:

```
   #!/bin/sh
   aisdispatcher -r -d /dev/ttyS0 -s 38400 -H 192.168.1.5:5001
```

Comment: The unit looks good but the service does not connect to the internet and as you say it works at expected. What we need is to know why your script does not connect to the internet. Can you please edit your question and add the script to it? Does the script runs on the command line?

Comment: But maybe it does not wait for the connection to be established? Is my Unit valid for Raspbian?

Comment: Have just answered. And yes your unit is valid for Raspbian. It is a general *systemd* unit and any distribution supporting *systemd* will work with it. Raspbian do it since *Jessie*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`network-online.target` is a static unit. You can check it with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl list-unit-files network-online.target
UNIT FILE             STATE
network-online.target static

1 unit files listed.
```

means it has no [Install] section and starts only if it is `Wants` or `Requires` by another unit. It cannot be started and stopped and does not run on bootup. But if it is not loaded then there is nothing to start `After=` and your unit will run without waiting for network-online.  Add this statement:

```
Wants=network-online.target
```

to the [Unit] section and look if it fixes your problem.

Comment: See also https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/ (which recommends the same thing as Ingo).  The crux of the issue here is that `After=` does not make something a pre-requisite, it just means if this is in play, wait until after that.  `Wants=` and `Requires=` create actual dependencies; see `man systemd.unit` (there is an index to all directives, BTW, in `man systemd.directives`, since they are spread across a number of man pages).

Comment: On a more sober note, this `systemd` stuff changes the way so many things are done. There are countless scripts offered online as solutions for this problem. These work of course, but as you've just shown, there are simpler and more elegant (?) ways to get the job done.

Comment: addition to 
@goldilocks comment,  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html

Comment: @jsotola very helpful, haven't seen it before. But you have to take a little bit of attention. The documentation is for *systemd 239*. Raspbian get stuck on *systemd 232* so there may be some issues documented which are not yet supported by Raspbian. If in doubt better to look at the man pages local.

Comment: @Ingo, almost all linux man pages are online .... just google the command .... ie. `man systemd.directives`